# Fill ReliableTopic's backing RingBuffer

Tags: hazelcast

Given a `ReliableTopic`, I am looking to fill the underlying buffer if the topic has been created (rather that joining to an existing topic)

Essentially, I want the backing `RingBuffer` to always be full with something.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you want to access the underlying RingBuffer?

Comment: @OzanKılıç - yes, but I don't want to mess around with the underlying buffer if its going to break the distributed nature of `ReliableTopic`, especially when joining an already existing cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for ReliableTopic creation events by [DistributedObjectListener](https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/3.11.1/manual/html-single/index.html#example-distributed-object-code) and access underlying ringbuffer and populate when it happens.